# Proof with Combinatorial Argument $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (i-1) = nC2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to prove below equation with combinatorial argument but I have no idea how this works.

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (i-1) = nC2$$

Can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think of the following problem. Given n points ($p_1,p_2,\ldots , p_n$) how many lines can be formed that join exactly 2 of those n points?. Well from $p_1$ we can draw $n-1$ lines, one joining it to $p_2$, another to $p_3$ and so on. Then from $p_2$ we can draw another $n-2$ lines, joining it to $p_3,p_4\ldots$.

So the total number of lines is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{(i-1)}$.

Can you think of a combinatorial argument for the total number of lines for this problem ?

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. Couldn't think of this kind of way exists!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Two ways of counting handshakes between $n$ persons.

- Take the number of handshakes between $2$ out of $n$ people:
  $\binom{n}{2}$
- The first person shakes hands of $n-1$, the second person shakes hands
  of $n-2$, and so on.